To what extent does saying "I'm sorry" acknowledge one's own fault?
This may be a duplicate, but I'm wondering how much I should be careful about saying sorry.
I'm Japanese, and often it is said that Japanese people say sorry too easily and it could cause troubles in English speaking countries. This may be partially true, but how dangerous is it really?
I noticed there are laws that provide "saying sorry does not imply acknowledging the guilt (in medical context?)", which looks a little ridiculous to me (though laws may be often ridiculous).
I suppose people say sorry meaning sorry about the situation, not sorry it's my fault, even in America. That should be why there are laws like above. And I assume not every American are so unreasonable to take sorry as an acknowledgment of guilt automatically.
Questions:

Is the above need to be careful to say sorry is generally restricted to America because of the nature of lawsuits there?
American or not, to what extent is sorry taken as acknowledging guilt?

The latter question may be opinion based, but I'm curious to know if saying sorry is REALLY something to be avoided e.g., when you are in a car accident.

Related:

When should I say I apologize and when should I say I am sorry?
Can "to be sorry" be used to apologize?
'Sorry' as a replacement for 'Excuse me'?


In Britain, we say 'sorry' very often for reasons of politeness, even if we have done nothing wrong. If one person bumps into another, often, both will say 'sorry', and American tourists say we say 'sorry' when they bump into us. Also we may say 'Sorry, but this isn't right!' e.g. when querying a bill in a restaurant.

Outside of the legal context, it would be very difficult to say to what extent saying "sorry" implies guilt.  There are too many contexts to consider, too many different language groups and language habits.  People in American and elsewhere say "sorry" a lot, and they mean different things by it.  As for the legal context, you can ask on Law Stack Exchange.  Americans who are not trained in law do not know these kinds on intricacies.  Personally, I'm under the impression that in legal matters, you should simply try to say as little as possible.

For a practitioner to say "sorry" to a patient when something has gone wrong is not an admission of negligence or malpractice in the context of tort law.  Not sure why you find that ridiculous.  Whether it applies to car accidents is a legal question and this is not the place to ask that.
